Is Cassandra 4.1.5 supported on RedHat 9?
Is cassandra 4.1.5 supported on Redhat 9.X.  Where can I find a doc or webpage stating this is a supported combination?

This is as close as you're going to get: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/installing/installing.html
Which states:

Apache Cassandra can be installed on a number of Linux distributions:

AlmaLinux
Amazon Linux Amazon Machine Images (AMIs)
Debian
RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)
SUSE Enterprise Linux
Ubuntu


"Where can I find a doc or webpage stating this is a supported combination?"
You can't. The above list is as close as we have to what you're asking. We simply don't test with every major Linux distro and version number. Typically, if something is a RedHat derivative (Fedora, Rocky, etc) it will run and be supported on both any other RedHat Linux or full-blown RHEL itself.

Yes, Cassandra 4.1 is supported to run on RHEL 9.
Current versions of Apache Cassandra -- 3.0*, 3.11*, 4.0, 4.1 and 5.0 -- are supported to run on recent releases of major Linux distributions.
[Strictly speaking, Cassandra 3.0 and 3.11 have recently been moved into "maintenance mode" with the release of 5.0 (in September 2024).]
I should point out that we (the project) don't formally test every single Linux distribution. We rely on vendors and enterprises to share the results of their performance and regression tests of Cassandra releases on various platforms.
For example, DataStax conducts platform certifications at scale (up to 1,000-node clusters). For full disclosure, I am an Apache Cassandra committer and work at DataStax. Vendors and enterprises who perform similar testing share it with the community so we know it works with those Linux distributions. Cheers!
